# Navigating the DOM: selecting ul childrens

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say that I have a nested `<ul>` that looks like this:

```
 <ul>
    <ul class="pizzatype">
      <h1>Margherita</h1>
      <li class="ingredient">Tomato sauce</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Mozzarella</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Origano</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pizzatype">
      <h1>Spicy salamino</h1>
      <li class="ingredient">Tomato sauce</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Mozzarella</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Salamino</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pizzatype">
      <h1>Onion n' Tuna</h1>
      <li class="ingredient">Tomato sauce</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Mozzarella</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Tuna</li>
      <li class="ingredient">Onion</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

And a script that console.log the childrens of class "pizzatype":

```
var pizzatype = document.querySelectorAll('.pizzatype');
console.log(pizzatype[1].children[3]);
```

The console.log at children[3] returns: `<li class="ingredient">Salamino</li>`

But I'm looking for a parameter that returns just `Salamino`

Anyone can help?

Also, is there any reference site that I can consult to find out which parameters can be asked, starting from the children function? Like children.text, children.value etc

Comment: You shouldn't have `<ul>` directly in `<ul>`. The elements of `<ul>` should be `<li>`.

Comment: @DNKROZ Please do not add answers as comments.

Comment: @zzzzBov that way, if I console.log(pizzatype[1].children[2]);, the console returns "undefined"

Comment: @MatteoBoscolo, I don't understand what you're trying to say, [correcting the markup works just fine](https://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/xLepZe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text of an element

```
console.log(pizzatype[1].children[3].textContent);
```

Comment: **not** `innerText`. That's IE-specific.

Comment: @Barmar, [not anymore it's not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

Comment: This is working on Chrome but with nested <ul><ul><li>, not with the <ul><li><li> version of it. If I switch to <ul><li><li>, I get "Cannot read property 'textContent'"

Comment: @MatteoBoscolo, Then you are not accessing the element the correct way. And `<li>` directly in `<li>` isn't valid html either

Comment: I fixed it structuring the html this way <ul><li><span>

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing is pointing to the `li` element it's self. You need to target the text of this element.

You can do this by using `.innerText`. You can also use `.innerHTML`, which will return the text in raw format and won't automatically encode/decode text.

```
console.log(pizzatype[1].children[3].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Don't think this deserves a -1, but you may want to consider explaining a little bit what you're doing.  Also you may want to consider using `innerText` as opposed to `innerHTML`